# position vector and direction vector in homogeneous coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

In homogeneous coordinates 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$ is supposed to be a position vector and the direction vector is 
$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
0\end{pmatrix}
$, but neither these vector point in the same direction nor do they have the same magnitude:
[vector image illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0zkJ.png)  . So I'm probably misunderstanding the concept of why the latter is called the direction vector. What is the idea behind it?

Comment: Without context it's difficult to know what the author intended. Homogeneous coordinates can be used in relation to the projective transform, to linearize an affine space, or in solutions to homogeneous polynomials. Without more information it's hard to say what they're doing.

Comment: well, there's no particular context, but I was studying affine transformation and it was mentioned the former was a location and the latter was a direction. But, I don't know why all this is leading to make the glm maths library compute `m*t` instead of `t*m`.  All the confusion is coming from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222806/how-does-glm-handle-translation?noredirect=1#comment104663763_59222806

Comment: The main motivation is that you can't do vector addition with matrix multiplication normally, but you can if you use homogeneous coordinates and an augmented matrix. This allows you to do affine operations using strictly matrix multiplication as well as normal matrix operations on the vectors such as projections and rotations. It's also useful for dealing with natural vision with vanishing points in the projective transform. You can read more here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix

Comment: I do get the idea of using the extra column for translation but, what I'm more confused about is if `t` is the translation vector i.e. [x, y, z, 1]represents we're translating by x in the x-direction , y in y-direc. and z in z-direc. and `m` is the transformation matrix of a certain linear transformation then how is `m*t` giving us the translation we require? Look at the code for how the translation is carried out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222806/how-does-glm-handle-translation?noredirect=1#comment104663763_59222806

Comment: as far as I have understood linear algebra the translation vector was supposed to be put in the 4th column of an identity matrix and then `t*m` should had been computed

Comment: Set up two matrices like this and multiply them using normal matrix multiplication. That will add the vectors as the last column of the new matrix. I recommend doing a few 3x3 examples by hand until you get a feel for it.

Comment: um.... I do know how matrix multiplication works, what I dont get is if `t` is the transformation matrix that *gives* the translation, then why is `m*t` giving the translation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102004/discussion-between-cyclotomicfield-and-juztcode).

Answer (score 3):

It’s important to keep in mind that the author is talking about points (“position vectors”) and directions *in the plane*, not in $\mathbb R^3$. The same apparent difficulty that you’re having with the homogeneous coordinates of points and directions arises if you compare homogeneous coordinates of two points on the plane. For example, $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ have the same direction in the sense that you’re using—they lie on the same ray from the origin—but their homogeneous coordinate vectors $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,1)$ do not.

This apparent problem is easily resolved, however. When you pass to homogeneous coordinates, you effectively embed $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$ as the plane $z=1$. The origin in $\mathbb R^2$ corresponds to the point $(0,0,1)$ on this plane. To see if two points have the same direction using homogeneous coordinates, you need to examine rays that emanate from this point, not from the origin of $\mathbb R^3$. It should be obvious that $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,1)$ do lie on a common ray from $(0,0,1)$.

In fact, we go a bit farther than this with homogeneous coordinates: we identify the point $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ with the entire line through the origin and the point $(x,y,1)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ (less the origin itself, for important technical reasons). That is, $(x,y,1)$ and $(kx,ky,k)$ with $k\ne0$ represent the same point in $\mathbb R^2$, and there is a one-to-one correspondence between points in $\mathbb R^2$ and lines in $\mathbb R^3$ that intersect the reference plane $z=1$.

What about the lines parallel to $z=1$, i.e., lines that are wholly contained in the $x$-$y$ plane? They don’t correspond to any points in $\mathbb R^2$, but they do have a geometric interpretation there. Since points in $\mathbb R^2$ correspond to lines through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$, lines in $\mathbb R^2$ correspond through planes through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$. These planes have unique perpendiculars through the origin, so they, too, can be represented by homogeneous coordinate triples. In fact, if the Cartesian equation of the line is $ax+by+c=0$, then its homogeneous coordinates are simply $\mathbf n=(a,b,c)$, so that the homogeneous equation of a line has the form $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf x=0$, but this is exactly what the equation of a plane through the origin in $\mathbb R^3$ looks like. The intersection of two such planes is a line that is perpendicular to both normals of the planes, so the intersection of two lines in $\mathbb R^2$ can be found by taking the cross product of their homogeneous coordinates.

Let’s see what happens when we do this for a pair of parallel lines: $$(a,b,c)\times(a,b,c')=(-b(c-c'),a(c-c'),0)$$ and since $c-c'\ne0$ we can divide by this common factor to get the equivalent coordinates $(-b,a,0)$. Since $c$ and $c'$ were arbitrary, we see that all of the lines with direction vector $(-b,a)$ have a common intersection with homogeneous coordinates $(-b,a)$. In terms of our 3-D embedding the the plane, this says that all planes that include the line $t(-b,a,0)$ intersect $z=1$ in parallel lines.

A little bit of thought should convince you that if you take a different family of parallel lines, you’ll get a common intersection point with different homogeneous coordinates. In this sense, we can say that the homogeneous coordinates $(-b,a,0)$ represent the common direction of the lines with equations of the form $ax+by+c=0$, or as the author puts it, the homogeneous coordinate vector $(-b,a,0)$ represents the direction vector $(-b,a)$ in the plane.

These additional points with a zero in the last place are called *points at infinity*. For completeness, we also add a line at infinity which goes through all of the points at infinity, but no others. This line corresponds to the $x$-$y$ plane in our 3-d embedding, so its homogeneous coordinates are $(0,0,1)$.